# Determine if two arrays are a rotated version of each other

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge

Following algorithm has time complexity \$O(N)\$ and space complexity \$O(1)\$.

Any suggestions to improve this algorithm or any alternate approach suggestions?

```
public static boolean isRotatedVersion(int[] a, int[] b){
        //Check length of arrays
        if(a.length != b.length)
            return false;

        //Declare two pointers. One for each array
        int aPointer = 0;
        int bPointer = 0;

        //This flag will prevent us walking through the 2nd array in a loop only once
        //Helps avoid going into infinite walk loop
        boolean isFirstTimeWalk = true;

        //This loop will run from 0 to n of array 1
        while(aPointer < a.length){

            //If elements at position aPointer and bPointer are equal then incr both pointer 
            // to move to the element in both array
            if(a[aPointer] == b[bPointer]){
                aPointer++;
                if(bPointer < b.length-1)
                    bPointer++;
                else{ //If reached end of second array then it reset pointer to 0 to rotate
                    //Once rotated done mark is1stTimeWalked to false so avoid future loops
                    isFirstTimeWalk = false;
                    bPointer = 0;
                }
            }else if(isFirstTimeWalk && bPointer < b.length-1){
                //Move bPointer until a match is found
                bPointer++;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it even theoretically possible to solve this problem in \$O(n)\$ time and \$O(1)\$ space?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Bug

I ran your code with the following arrays and your function thought that the two arrays were rotated versions of each other but they were not:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int [] a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 0 };
    int [] b = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
    System.out.println(isRotatedVersion(a, b));
}
```

Output:

> true

#### Achieving a correct \$O(n)\$ solution

Determining if an array is a rotated version of another array is equivalent to searching for the first array within the second array concatenated with itself.  For example, given:

```
a = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 0 }
b = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 }
```

You can search for pattern `a` within this array, which is `b` doubled:

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 }
```

To do this in \$O(n)\$ time, you just need to implement a linear time string searching algorithm.  I would suggest using the [Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), which is easy to understand and implement.

Comment: @AKh First, you shouldn't change the question after an answer has been posted.  Second, your new code fails on these arrays: `{ 0, 0, 1, 2, 0 } and { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2 }.`

Comment: Minor detail: `b` needn't be concatenated with whole itself, the last item can be omitted.

Comment: @CiaPan Correct.  Also, if I were doing it I would just use wraparound indexing on the original `b` array instead of creating a doubled one.

Answer (score -1):

somehow your code looks quite complex an is hard to understand although you added lots of comments.

I tried to create my own version following the TDD work flow (test methods have been created in order of appearance and logic has been improved with each failing test):

```
public class IsRotatedArrayCheckTest {

    private static class IsRotatedArrayCheck {
        public boolean isRotatedVersion(int[] a, int[] b) {
            if (a.length != b.length)
                return false; // arrays of differing lenght cannot be rotated versions
            for (int offset = 0; offset < a.length; offset++) { // rotation may start at any offset
                if (isRotatedWithOffset(a, b, offset))
                    return true;
            }
            return false; // all indexes checked with no success
        }

        private boolean isRotatedWithOffset(int[] a, int[] b, int offset) {
            for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
                if (a[index] != b[calculateRotatedIndex(offset, a.length, index)])
                    return false;
            }
            return true; // all values matched with this offset
        }

        private int calculateRotatedIndex(int offset, int arrayLength, int currentIndex) {
            return (offset + currentIndex) % arrayLength;
        }
    }

    // test code begins here
    private static final IsRotatedArrayCheck IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK = new IsRotatedArrayCheck();

    @Test
    public void same_array_is_rotated() throws Exception {
        int[] test1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] test2 = test1;
        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertTrue("same array is rotated", isRotatedArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void shorter_array_is_not_rotated() throws Exception {
        int[] test1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] test2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(test1, 2, test1.length);
        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertFalse("arrays not same size", isRotatedArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void longer_array_is_not_rotated() throws Exception {
        int[] test2 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] test1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(test2, 2, test2.length);
        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertFalse("arrays not same size", isRotatedArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void not_same_numbers_is_not_rotated() throws Exception {
        int[] test1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] test2 = Arrays.copyOf(test1, test1.length);
        test2[2] = 7;

        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertFalse("arrays have differing values", isRotatedArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void no_repeated_digits() throws Exception {
        int[] test1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] test2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0 };
        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertTrue("no repeated digits offset 1", isRotatedArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void repeated_digits() throws Exception {
        int[] test1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5 };
        int[] test2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0 };
        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertTrue("repeated digits offset 1", isRotatedArray);
    }

    @Test
    public void repeated_digits2() throws Exception {
        int[] test1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 };
        int[] test2 = new int[] { 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1 };
        boolean isRotatedArray = IS_ROTATED_ARRAY_CHECK.isRotatedVersion(test1, test2);
        assertTrue("repeated digits offset 2", isRotatedArray);
    }
}
```

What do you think about that?

---

> This `O(N^2)` algorithm. Cannot be the best solution. – AKh

There is no solution for the problem with less than `O(N^2)` (worst case).

The reason is that you have to compare each an every element of both arrays to prove that they are equal with the chosen offset. There are some special cases (which are somewhat likely) where the values within the array differ enough so that you can aboard the compare after having checked enough values.

eg with the input

```
 a= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} 
 b= { 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

you need only one check per offset -> `O(N)`

but with

```
 a= { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7} 
 b= { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1}
```

you need to check (almost) all elements ->`O(N^2)`. The fact that you safe one single compare does not change the time complexity...

You might come up with the idea to check the array for possible duplicated sub arrays, but that would only add another power to `N` (at least).

However: Time complexity always considers the *worst case*, therefor the solution cannot be better than `O(N^2)`.

---

The OP stated that her algorithm is has time complexity of `O(N)` but that is not true. She might have based that conclusion on the fact that there is only one loop visible, but her code does the second loop *implicitly*.

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @Vogel612 As user JS1 shows in the answer and in the following comment, the original code is **broken** (it doesn't do what it should), so there's nothing to review (according to the site's rules)...

Comment: @CiaPan you are aware that this **also** means that this answer should be deleted??

Comment: This O(N^2) algorithm. Cannot be the best solution.

Comment: The statement that there can't be a `O(n)` solution is obviously wrong (see @JS1's answer). Also the OP's code, even though buggy, is not `O(n^2)` since `b` array is only iterated at most once in total. In order for it to be a `O(n^2)` complexity it would have to iterate b once for every element in `a` which it doesn't. The code stops after b was iterated once and the elements at the current indices don't match.

Comment: @ChrisWue The reasoning in this post is wrong. The argument is **only true if** the second array is **shifted by `0` (best case)**. In any other case you move on with the check for equality until you find a differing value. Then you have to increment (or otherwise select a new value for) the rotation offset and do the check **for all elements again**. Therefore there is no `O(N)` solution. I admit that in worst case (my second example) you can cancel the equality seach after `N/2` in average. But constant factors are ignored in time complexity calculations.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: No you don't have to start from the beginning if you find a mis-match. Check out the description for the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) - in essence it pre-computes a partial match table in `O(n)` and then searches in `O(n)` as well (utilizing the pre-computed partial match table) yielding overall `O(n)`

Comment: @ChrisWue *"it pre-computes a partial match table in O(n)"* but whe are not looking for a *partitial match*, we are looking for a **complete match with rotation offset**.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: Yes, the partial match table help KMP to skip partial matches and accelerate the search. KMP finds the full pattern of course.

Comment: @ChrisWue: that's what I mean: to find the full match the algorithm needs to iterate **all `N` one time** -> `O(N)`. To find the right *rotation offset* (at which all `N`are completely iterated for the sake of the check) it needs to iterate  (at most) **all `N` a nother time** -> `O(N^2)`

Comment: For O(n) solution, I have Z-Algorithms solutions in my mind. First, find Z-array for A+B and then Z function for B+A, this way you can compare them.